# Browser Compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, dreamweaver

## Problem 1

### Browser Compatibility

I use Dreamweaver CS5.
I have all the major Browsers installed on my system to have my sites checked with all of them.

I recently designed a site that enabled users to sign in to our Company Site.

It worked very well in all other browsers but when i tried it on my Internet Explorer; it was just a disaster.

First of all, all the objects were misplaced.

---

## Problem 2

### Repeated Clicks

Another site of mine works fine in all browsers and versions. (TESTED @ Adobe Browser Lab)
But when I opened that site in the host machine @ Internet Explorer it makes multiple click sound. Hearing the sound I feel like the address is demanded with too many clicks. At the end IE stops working...!

Please Help Me !

Comment: Simplest solution: tell users to not use IE. next solution: post some actual errors/code samples, because right now, your question is completely unanswerable. Voting to close.

Comment: Do your pages have a DOCTYPE? Are any JavaScript errors thrown in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really rely on WYSIWYG editors for producing cross platform designs. The only real way to get it working correctly is by manually editing the css/html and testing as you go.